# iOS Swift - Prevent OS from killing app in background mode?

Tags: ios, swift, background-process, terminate, suspend

I've created an app that takes in bluetooth data from a local device and uploads it to a database. I'd like to be able to keep doing this indefinitely when the app is pushed to the background or if the phone is put into lock/sleep mode.

I've edited Plist info to allow CoreBlueTooth and network content to be enabled while in background mode. Using this and a couple memory saving tweaks for when the app gets pushed into the background, I'm able to hit just under 4 hours of operation when the app is pushed to background and the phone is put to lock/sleep. However, after 4 hours the phone seems to automatically terminate the app completely (while being at over 80% battery life).

Is there any way to prevent iOS from terminating suspended apps and ensure that they run indefinitely (until battery runs out)?

Thanks!

Comment: You've gone through https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html ?

Comment: Yes...I've tried playing around with looping tasks in the beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler and applicationDidEnterBackground methods. Neither of them worked in terms of extending runtime past a few minutes. The PList edits to enable CoreBluetooth and Fetch data have enabled my app to run for up to 4 hours though.

Comment: Audio might be your best bet - play something silent to keep it going.

Comment: I've seen that method...perhaps that may be the way to go here. Thanks for the suggestion!